# What do curly brackets mean in a variable declaration?

Tags: javascript, string, variables, character-arrays

What do curly brackets (`{}`) do in variable declarations, when surrounding multiple pairs of the form `integer:string`?

For example, what do they mean here?

```
char = {0:'(',3:') ',6:' - '};
```

In this case, it's from the following phone number formatting script:

```
function formatPhone(obj) {
    var numbers = obj.value.replace(/\D/g, ''),
    char = {0:'(',3:') ',6:' - '};
    obj.value = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        obj.value += (char[i]||'') + numbers[i];
    }
}
```

I believe that the line defining `char` is the one that's causing it to fail.

Comment: That statement isn't causing your problem. What's going wrong, exactly? I'll see if I can help with that, too.

Comment: Could you accept an answer if any of them helped?

Answer (score 3):

This is a Javascript object. Better indented, it would look like this:

```
char = {
    0: '(',
    3: ') ',
    6: ' - '
}
```

It's saying that you're making an object with properties `0`, `3`, and `6` set to the given values. Then, the properties are accessed with `char[i]`, which returns `null` unless the property is defined -- so for all `i` except 0, 3, and 6, it'll default to `''`. For 0, 3, and 6, it'll take the relevant strings.

Alright, I think I figured out what's 'not working', though again I'd need you to explain what that means before I can be sure.

This line:

```
obj.value += (char[i]||'') + numbers[i];
```

will insert `undefined` in the string if `numbers[i]` isn't defined, and `numbers[i]` is only defined for `i` = 0, 3, or 6. Change the line to this:

```
obj.value += (char[i]||'') + (numbers[i]||'');
```

and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

It creates an object:

```
obj = {0:'(',3:') ',6:' - '};
```

You have two elements inside your object with keys 0, 3 and 6. You can access them obj[0], obj[3] and obj[6]

Or you can access them in a loop as you did in your example

Comment: Actually, there's `3` between 0 and 6.

Comment: Always ready to help someone make a better answer than mine and steal all my rep! ;) Which reminds me -- you'd access numbered properties with `obj[_]`, not `obj._`.

Comment: 10 points to Griffindor)), Thanks to @QPaysTaxes. You got your rep I guess))

Answer (score 1):

That is a Javascript object.

> In addition to creating objects using a constructor function, you can
>   create objects using an object initializer. Using object initializers
>   is sometimes referred to as creating objects with literal notation.
>   "Object initializer" is consistent with the terminology used by C++.
>
> The syntax for an object using an object initializer is:
>
> ```
> var obj = { property_1:   value_1,   // property_# may be an identifier...
>             2:            value_2,   // or a number...
>             // ...,
>             "property n": value_n }; // or a string
> ```
>
> where obj is the name of the new object, each `property_i` is an
>   identifier (either a name, a number, or a string literal), and each
>   `value_i` is an expression whose value is assigned to the
>   `property_i`.

The rest of this article is available [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Creating_new_objects).

Comment: Please add a relevant excerpt from the bit you linked. As-is, your answer is _severely_ lacking -- what happens if that link dies?

Comment: I thought the link would expand automatically, but apparently I had to "approve" that functionality.  AJ, thanks for the tip.

Comment: @Alan, you had to approve my edit that expanded the link and fiddled with the text. It doesn't automatically know what to paste in. Nor does it know how to format it. In the future, please do it yourself -- while it's not that difficult, it _is_ a pain in the butt.